# Spring Cloud Zuul does not forward cookies

Tags: cookies, spring-boot, netflix-zuul, spring-cloud-netflix

I am facing a problem with spring cloud Zuul proxy. I hace two microservices configured, up and running. I have a cookie in my web browser and I am using Zuul as an API Gateway, When I hit Zuul to call my Backend, Zuul is not forwarding my cookie to my Backend, It seems that Zuul is ignoring the cookie sent and my Backend is not able to retrieve this.

Can you please help me with this issue?, I am using Spring cloud Brixton.RELEASE and spring boot 1.3.5

Regards.

Answer (score -3, accepted):

I have solved this problem just passing the data sent in my cookie using simple http headers.

Comment: Doing this with HTTP Only Headers, such as the cookies, would allow a client to spoof security checks or modify server-side cookie data.

Answer (score 13):

In Spring Cloud Netflix 1.1, "Cookies" is included in the sensitive headers list and they are not passed down.

This can be manipulated by config zuul.routes.*.sensitiveHeaders.

See documentation details here under heading "Cookies and Sensitive Headers":

http://cloud.spring.io/spring-cloud-netflix/spring-cloud-netflix.html

Comment: Thanks for reply, Let me try your suggestion.

Comment: Take a look at ZuulProperties class. There are two ways to configure sensitive headers, one globally and for each route. Set-Cookie and Cookie are included by default. To enable them, you need to override this with something else. For example:
zuul.sensitiveHeaders: Authorization

Comment: I read through the docs above, but those docs don't exactly spell out how you "override" the defaults. I didn't automatically make the assumption that if I specified a new value for sensitiveHeaders that the defaults (Cookie,Set-Cookie,Authorization) would be unset. However I can confirm that setting the value to something different does unset the default completely. Thanks @qza for the helpful tip.

Answer (score 2):

Default Zuul sensitive headers allowing to not forward these datas are

```
sensitiveHeaders=Cookie,Set-Cookie,Authorization
```

to be able to forward cookies, you can put in your bootstrap.properties file

```
sensitiveHeaders=
```

Or if you don't need of Authorization header

```
sensitiveHeaders=Authorization
```

Answer (score 1):

Add sensitive headers in application.yml like this:-

```
routes:
service:
  path: /service/**
  sensitiveHeaders: Cookie,Set-Cookie
  url: http://localhost:9001
```